# Updating NSManagedObjects in a "display" MOC when they're changed in "scratchpad" MOC

Tags: ios, core-data, ios6, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Let's say that I have a display MOC that is used to display address book contacts that are fetched from a web service. Elsewhere in the app I have a search feature that searches the web service given a query entered by the user, and I fetch and store those objects in a scratchpad MOC so that it doesn't "pollute" the display fed by the display MOC.

Now let's say the user modifies a contact in the scratchpad MOC. I'd like to synchronize these changes to any equivalent object in the display MOC, if they exist. I don't want the changed object to be added to the display MOC if it isn't already there, and I'd like the change to work the other way too (say if the user changes a contact in the display MOC, it should change in the scratchpad MOC, but only if an equivalent object already exists there). I don't want either MOCs to have objects added to them as a result of an object update. Making the scratchpad MOC a child of the display MOC sounds like the wrong solution.

What is the best pattern to ensure that equivalent objects in different MOCs stay in sync without changing the complement of objects in any other MOC?

Answer (score 1):

This is the purpose of `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`. Whenever a context saves changes, this notification is automatically posted, along with information about what changed. Observe this notification, and use the `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` method to take changes saved on one context and merge them into another one.

Comment: Wouldn't this also merge objects that exist in one MOC and not the other? I only want to merge those objects that exist in both MOCs. If an object doesn't exist in the other MOC, I don't want it merging over.

Comment: Do the different MOCs use different persistent store files? Because if not then it's kind of a meaningless question. Objects exist in the persistent store, and a MOC may or may not load them depending on what fetches you perform or relationships you traverse.

Comment: Yes, the scratchpad MOC is attached to an in-memory PSC. My question relates to syncing objects that exist in both MOCs but not syncing those that only exist in one or the other. I'm not sure why you think it's meaningless, given the use case I gave.